# Where is the Aves game engine?

Tags: javascript, html5

The [Aves game engine](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ol3qQ4CEUTo) made a splash last spring/summer, with very impressive demo videos. I went back to check on them, and it looks like their site has long since died. Google also doesn't seem to know anything new about them.

Where can I find news about Aves? Is the project dead?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Dextrose was acquired by Zynga ( creators of Farmville, mafia wars )

http://www.insidesocialgames.com/2010/09/24/zynga-acquires-dextrose-aves-engine-html5/

Answer (score 2):

While [momboco's answer](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/14454/where-is-the-aves-game-engine/14455#14455) is indeed the case the tech talks and other presentations on the engine have a lot of useful information about game development using HTML5 and ***not*** using canvas. I have used a few of these tricks in my latest project and built a scrolling map world rendering through HTML and CSS including an isometric view with a good deal of success.

Answer (score 2):

Paul Bakaus shared some info in a 26 Oct 2012 comment on [this Google Talk video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_RRnyChxijA).

> As creator of the engine, let me chime in. You are partially right in that we have never released the full blown iso engine, but we did in fact release individual components of it at https://github.com/zynga.
>
> Most notably our state-of-the-art build system Jasy (https://github.com/zynga/jasy), our JavaScript foundation Core (https://github.com/zynga/core), and a couple of highly performance optimized frontend components such as Scroller (https://github.com/zynga/scroller) or Viewporter (https://github.com/zynga/viewporter).
>
> I know you'd really like to see more isometric game-centric code, and hey, never say never. We need more people like you pushing for it to make it happen.

In a [conversation with Jason Mayes on Google+](https://plus.google.com/u/0/+JasonMayes/posts/PFJ4TMzrAWi) he also states "Some of the content is outdated now though, Canvas is definitely a viable tech to build games now :)"

Comment: these were not the answers i was hoping for :(

Comment: It's a shame, but Paul is [working for Google now](http://paulbakaus.com/about/), so who knows what the next magic he'll cook up is! : - )